# Kubuntu freezes whenever I boot my laptop on battery. Why?

Tags: boot, kubuntu, power-management, battery, debugging

I have installed Kubuntu(v19.10) and since the first day, I'm facing this really annoying bug which freezes up my laptop([ASUS FX505DT](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DD-DT-DU/specifications/)).

#### The issue

I face this bug whenever I boot my laptop on battery. *The laptop freezes whenever I try to use Plasma(e.g. opening the context menu)*. Additionally the boot time on battery(approx. 20s) is way more than on AC power(approx. 5s). **Weirdly, booting my laptop first on AC power, and then remove the power doesn't cause any issues.**

Please help me in debugging this issue as it is highly hindering my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with the kernel being old, for the relatively new AMD Ryzen 3550H processor in my laptop.
I'm currently using `linux v5.6-rc5` without any issues to date.

Comment: Hello @Utkarsh I am facing that issue right now. Could you please tell us you you solved it in a more detailed way? My computer is an `ASUS ZenBook 14 UM431DA-AM022 - FullHD (Ryzen 7 3700U, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD, AMD Radeon RX Vega 10`

Comment: You can refer to this answer for more details. https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade

Comment: Thanks a lot @Utkarsh Verma